# Is it possible to have Develop branch with source code and Master branch with dist only

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

The problem I want to address is related to a specific folder of my project: `angular`

[image: angular folder]

What I would like to do is

- be able to add the `dist` folder to the **master branch**
- be able to add the other folders (except `dist`) to **develop branch**
- Merges would not change these two rules.

With these rules setup, I would be working on my **develop branch** and at some point I would merge changes to master to deploy on a live server, but this merge would still ignore the "source code" folders that has been committed to **develop**.

Since this project have other folders besides `angular`, there would be changes in other folders that I would want to merge from **develop** to **master**.

Is this even possible?

*Of course, I have a .gitignore on node_modules that ignores the whole folder except the .gitignore itself.*

Comment: while it may be possible to do it with some weird schema, it is very unlikely git would want you to do things that way...it doesn't seem 'git idiomatic'

Comment: @pedrorijo91 should I just keep both sources and dist in the repository by default and not worry about it?

Comment: I would say yes, just keep both on same git branch